# Zend Framework JOIN & MVC best practices

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, join, frameworks

Hi I am fairly new to Zend framework.

I am working with a tutorial found here: 
http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/.

In order to explore more, I created another table in my database called recordLabel which contains an id, a name and an address.

While after many trials I finally managed to do my join, I realize that the code for it was implemented in the Controller.

My question is a simple one, is it not better for this code that manages data to sit in a Model rather than a Controller ?

I have to models: Albums and RecordLabel, in which of these should it sit then ?

Comment: It's a good question. You're probably looking for a short answer: in the Album model. But there is a long answer that talks about ORM's like [Doctrine](http://ww.doctrine-project.org/).

Comment: thanks for the tip, that is also what I thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `one artist` can have many `albums` and each one have a single `record label` I would put this query in the `album` model part of a get method like :

```
$select = $table->select()
    ->from('album')
    ->join('record_label',
        'album.record_label_id = record_label.id);
```

If on the other hand, an `album` can have many releases on different labels, I would put it in the `record label`, part of a method `getRecordLabelByAlbum($albumId)`.